Getting AsRock BIOS to display on DP monitor not the HDMI monitor
I have a large monitor which has worked great since day 1. Two days ago I added a 7 inch display for ADA64 display and now whenever I boot the boot display goes there. Ever try and read a BIOS on a 7" screen??? Is there a way in BIOS I can say "Display here, not there"?
I have an AsRock X670E with the 2.1 BIOS installed. I'm running Windows 10 on it though the OS doesn't come into play at this point. The monitor is connected via DisplayPort so it can fully use refresh rates. The little screen is connected via HDMI.

Have you checked settings in the BIOS/UEFI? I have seen some Desktop firmware offer settings to determine display preference for the firmware interface, and some not. Those that don't offer an option will usually have a predefined hierarchy to the available display connectors and this cannot be changed. So, check your firmware settings and see if you see options regarding this.

I found the answer. I was looking at other posts and in a seemingly unconnected post they mentioned the order of the monitors on the video card. I ran around and saw the main monitor was on the far left and the only HDMI was on the right. I assumed order was left to right but then this was made in China. Move the DP cable to the first connector left of the HDMI and voila BIOS displayed properly.
